# Doxygen does not produce links in Markdown inline code comments

Tags: hyperlink, comments, markdown, doxygen

I'm trying to write some documentation in a Markdown file that will get processed by Doxygen. Everything works fine, except that in my inline code blocks, comments do not trigger Doxygen link generation. In fact, I think Doxygen simply "turns" off in such comments, as none of its commands seem to work, and the text is simply printed literally.

An example:

```
~~~.cpp
// Here be some code
MyClass x; // (a)

// (b) For another option for y, see MyClass2
OtherClass y;
~~~
```

In (a) `MyClass` is correctly linked to its corresponding documentation page. In (b), however, `MyClass2` fails to be linked. I've tried to use @ref, < a href="" > and other commands to no avail. Any ideas on how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try `~~~{.cpp}` instead as suggested by the manual: http://www.doxygen.org/manual/markdown.html#md_fenced

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working - nothing changes in fact. Identifiers in comments are still not highlighted.